# Is it possible to add properties to multiple files after they have been uploaded to artifactory?

Tags: artifactory, artifactory-query-lang

As the title says. Due to a lack of understanding about how best to query files in artifactory I now have a situation where I have a few hundred files I need to add the same properties to. 
Can this be done in bulk?
the folder structure looks like this:

```
repository
  |
  |- main folder
      |
      |- type
          |
          |- language1
              |
              |-sub-folder1
              |-sub-folder2
                 |-file1
                 |-file2
                 ...
              ...
          ...
```

Each sub-folder can have around 5 files, each language folder can have many sub-folders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure it is.
You have two main options.
The first one is to use the [Set Item Properties](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-SetItemProperties) REST API on the relevant folder with the "recursiveProperties=1".
The second option, which I believe is better, will be to [use the JFrog CLI](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory) to [set properties on existing artifacts](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-SettingPropertiesonFiles). This options will provide you with the ability to define a more complex logic on setting the properties.